# Creating a dataframe from text files, in pyspark does not work

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

Following is the code to read  list of data files that are separated by ^ into a data frame. However, each field is loaded as a separate row instead of reading row by row.

In other words, one row contains only one field and not all fields of a line.

This is done inside python spark of Databricks.

The fields are separated by ^.

```
df = spark.read.text(paths='path/srcfilepath',lineSep='^')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`spark.read.csv`** instead of `text` with **delimiter** option `^`

```
spark.read.option("delimiter","^").csv("path/srcfilepath").show()
```